# Get ID of block placed by player in server side script?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I'm creating a behavior pack and I need to detect the ID of a block placed by a player. The `player_placed_block` event doesn't give me an ID with the event data, it only gives me a three-dimensional coordinate of where the block was placed, and which player placed it:

[image: Player placed block documentation.]

There's also a `getBlock` method, which would work great with the coordinates I get back from the `player_plaed_block` event; however, it requires a ticking area:

[image: Get block documentation.]

The problem with `getBlock` is that I can't find anything in the documentation for getting the ticking area of the player, and the only thing I could find on the web was a ticket for code that didn't work, and seemed to require the `tickingarea` command to be ran in game first, which defeats the purpose of my script.

---

Is there a way to not only know the position and player, but also the type of block placed?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is from the community-ran bedrock(dawt)dev website? I recommend checking their Wiki / Guides which is also updated by the community.

Answer (score 0):

As of `@minecraft/server` version **1.9.0-beta**, the `dimension.getBlock()` method no longer requires a ticking area. However, as [`playerPlaceBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/playerplaceblockafterevent?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable) extends [BlockEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/blockevent?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable), you can now access the block directly instead of via its coordinates.

Working Example:

```
import { world } from "@minecraft/server"

world.afterEvents.playerPlaceBlock.subscribe(event => {
    console.warn(event.block.typeId);
});
```

*References (Linked):* The Microsoft Learn documentation, which I have found to be generally reliable and up-to-date.

Comment: This requires functionality that has not yet been added to the latest stable version (1.8.0), so it will require enabling the 'Beta APIs' toggle under "Experiments."